# How to set the language level in Gradle ? (so it is IDE-agnostic)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I would like to set the java language level in gradle, in an IDE-agnostic fashion.

`sourceCompatibility = 1.x` at the root level seems deprecated in Gradle 2.21.

(edit: or is it? IntelliJ gives me a groovy inspection error)

So I found this, which works.

```
idea {
    project {
        languageLevel = '1.7'
    }
}
```

But doesn't the configuration here tie gradle to IntelliJ IDEA, because of the `idea { }` structure...

Is there a way to do this in an IDE-agnostic fashion?

I would like my gradle build script to run in *any* IDE (be it IntelliJ IDEA or Eclipse) or on Jenkins (or whatever).

Comment: `languageLevel` should default to [sourceCompatibility](https://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.plugins.ide.idea.model.IdeaProject.html#org.gradle.plugins.ide.idea.model.IdeaProject:languageLevel). Are you sure that it was deprecated?

Comment: Using gradle for builds does not bind u to use a ide. You may use the gradle wrapper 'gradlew' and build on cli. then its the devs responsibility to integrate with particular proj configs of thier ide

Comment: @lifus okay, thanks, `sourceCompatability` did actually work. Weird, I was getting a Groovy inspection error: "Assignment is not used" from `sourceCompatibility = 1.7`. Is it ok to write `project.sourceCompatibility = 1.7` ?

Comment: It looks like a false positive. `project.sourceCompatibility` is equivalent to `sourceCompatibility` at the outermost level.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use Gradle in command line, the language level works fines as specified in `build.gradle` file.

But When import Gradle java project into IntelliJ IDEA, Gradle's plugin take responsibility to generate IDEA's project setting files,

Unfortunately, the plug in does not respect build.gradle's sourceCompatibility/targetCompatibility property, 
instead, it use IDEA's setting: 

`File -> Other Settings -> Default Project Structure -> Project Language Level -> 6 (By default).`

[image]

So, i think this is a bug of gradle's idea plugin. see https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-2198

Currently, i have to change language level in above dialog sometimes.

Answer (score 12):

The way to do this for CLI builds is shown. However I'm not sure if every IDE will pick this up.

```
allprojects {
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        sourceCompatibility = '1.7'
        targetCompatibility = '1.7'
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Adding this as an answer since I got it from the comments:

Instead of having sourceCompatibility/targetCompatibility in the compileJava task, use:

```
project.sourceCompatibility = '1.7'
project.targetCompatibility = '1.7'
```

in the configuration for the relevant projects

Comment: This worked for me in the setup: Gradle 6.2.2 + Kotlin 1.3 project + IntelliJ 2020.1

Answer (score 3):

If they are defined under `compileJava` you won't get the warning and IntelliJ and gradle both respect it.

```
compileJava {
    sourceCompatibility = '1.7'
    targetCompatibility = '1.7'
}
```

As with any gradle file change, you will need sync to get IntelliJ to pick up changes.

[image: Sync]

Answer (score 3):

inside of the `android` closure of your build.gradle inside your app module:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    // etc
    // other things

    // add this
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I tested the following on Gradle 6.1 and it works:

```
java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
}
```